# Incorrect datetime value when setting up Django with MySQL

Tags: mysql, django

I am trying to set up Django with MySQL on a Mac. This is my setup:

- Django 1.9
- Mysql 5.6.23
- OS X 10.11

For the data communication, I use MySQL Connector.

I have modified the `settings.py` file, so that Django can talk to MySQL. 
The problem is when I do `python manage.py migrate`, I keep getting this error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Incorrect datetime value:
'2016-01-11 06:59:07.980679+00:00' for column 'applied' at row 1.
```

What is wrong with this datetime format?

Answer (score 4):

Please go to settings.py under your project directory and change USE_TZ to false

```
USE_TZ = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this [bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26113). Looks like this issue has been reported as a bug. Though I don't know what they mean by *closed bug (invalid)*.

I have faced the same problem. I have switched to django 1.8.7, and it is working perfectly.

Comment: It was marked as invalid as it's a bug on the connector and it has to be reported to mysql rather than to Django.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, looks like the formatting is not correct for MySql

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48704/mysql-5-6-datetime-incorrect-datetime-value-2013-08-25t1700000000-with-er