# Django Error - django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Data truncated for column 'applied' at row 1

Tags: python, django, python-3.5

I am getting a weird issue when executing `python manage.py migrate`.

Below is the error.

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: Data truncated for column 'applied' at row 1

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Here is my models.py data

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Make sure each ForeignKey has `on_delete` set to the desired behavior.
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Threads(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    supplier = models.CharField(db_column='Supplier', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    activethreads = models.CharField(db_column='ActiveThreads', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    threadscreated = models.CharField(db_column='ThreadsCreated', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    ipaddress = models.CharField(db_column='IPAddress', max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Threads'


class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_content_type'
        unique_together = (('app_label', 'model'),)


class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_migrations'
```

Comment: Show us your model and migration

Comment: Deselect NN and see what happens, otherwise post more context.

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev - i have added model data in my question

Comment: @almostabeginner - I tried that, no luck.

Comment: Check settings.py --> Databases. Are you using mysql?

Comment: @almostabeginner - Yes i am using mysql

Comment: applied is column of django_migrations table, it seems to be an issue with this table.

Answer (score 2):

Solution of my problem is mentioned on the below URL, this is a bug with the latest version of Django. You need to change USE_TZ = False in settings.py

[Incorrect datetime value when setting up Django with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716360/incorrect-datetime-value-when-setting-up-django-with-mysql)

After doing the above change then you will encounter a different issue while running "python manage.py migrate" which will give you the below error

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'

For this issue please refer Chris Barrett solution mentioned below

https://bitbucket.org/Manfre/django-mssql/issues/80/error-when-using-django-19

You need to make the required changes in versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/operations.py (Check your setup) and make the changes

```
def bulk_insert_sql(self, fields, placeholder_rows):
        """
        Format the SQL for bulk insert
        """
        placeholder_rows_sql = (", ".join(row) for row in placeholder_rows)
        values_sql = ", ".join("(%s)" % sql for sql in placeholder_rows_sql)
        return "VALUES " + values_sql
```